# Android - How to make button to swap fullscreen mode and current size video

Tags: android, video

I have some question for my videos player project.I try to make button to swap video size from current size to full screen mode and I want to add this to my media controller too.My project has only landscape screen.Please help me to solve this problem. :(

Here is my application design.
[image]

And here's my xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MoviePlayerActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/HeadPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/img_back" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnBrightness"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/img_brightness" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeadTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/movie_title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/xhead"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ContentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/VideoPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vdoMovie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/VideoDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_corner"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMovieTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/body" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/list_bg"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#242424"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_bg_select" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry for my language skill.Thanks :)

Comment: can you show us what u have tried?show us your XML file

Comment: Now I add my xml code to my question. :)